# PhpStorm ignore generated code on reformat

Tags: php, phpstorm, autoformatting, reformat

is it possible that PhpStorm don't reformat files, which are generated from another program?
Is there a PHPDoc comment (something like `/** @generatedFile */`) that excludes a file from reformatting?

Comment: So what is the programming problem you are having?

Comment: @Crackertastic "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming**." - What do you think PHPStorm is used for?

Comment: @GolezTrol Forgive me if it was out of line.  I flagged as unclear not because of PHPStorm or reformatting, but the reference to `@generatedFile` threw me off.  I've used PHPDoc and have never seen that tag nor is it [listed as one of their tags in the documentation](http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/index.html).

Comment: I think `@generatedFile` is just a suggestion for a kind of tag OP is looking for, more of an example name that could have been used for a tag like that.

Comment: @GolezTrol Hmmm....OP may wish to re-word that section, it is unclear.  However I can concur that you may be right about it being a suggestion.  I will remove the DV once edited (can't until it is), but I am restricted from removing the flag.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `//@formatter:off` and `//@formatter:on` to define a region that should be ignored by the formatter. If it's possible, add those at the beginning an end of the generated files.

See: http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/reformatting-source-code.html